# Automatically show a blank page in a folder without a default html page

Tags: redirect, directory

In my site I have many folders that holds different type of files.

```
/img/
/js/
/styles/
/files/
```

(I have 20 more and I will add more eventually)

Currently, I have in each folder a `index.html` (my default directory) that has a meta tag redirect to the web root level.

Is there a better method or an easier way to redirect dynamically these folders to the web root without creating a file everytime?

**Edit:** I am using: `CentOS 5.7 + Apache 2 + php 5.3.5 + MySQL 5.1`

Thank you

Comment: What sort of server is this running on?

Comment: I updated my question sorry about that

Comment: Not a problem, but someone will be able to help you better now. I'm unfamiliar with Apache setup, but I'm guessing maybe something with .htaccess or something along those lines.

Comment: @DoozerBlake is right, that can be done in .htaccess how often you create subfolders? what kind, are they like users when someone register?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not think there's a mod for what you need. Here's what I suggest:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(img|js|styles|files)/?$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This way, if someone request http://www.domain.com/img/, he will automatically get redirected to the main page.

OR if you prefer:

```
RewriteRule ^(img|js)/?$ - [F]
```

that will give a permission denied.